# Regular expression for "The" or "the" in the text "The other one there, the blithe one."

Tags: regex

I have the following text `"The other one there, the blithe one."` I want to write a regular expression to match occurrences of `"The"` or `"the"`. My solution is `[^A-za-z][Tt]he[^A-za-z]`. When I input this into online regular expression tools I only get a match on "the". Is my code correct or incorrect? If it is incorrect what is a solution to find matches for `"The"` or `"the"` in text. Thank you in advance for any solution, advice or explanation you can offer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
\b[Tt]he\b
```

Here, `\b` indicates a word boundary.

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wD5rG8/1)

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way of matching entire words with regexp - you can use "word boundary" anchors, like this:

```
\b[Tt]he\b
```

Your regex is incorrect, because it would not match `The` at the beginning or at the end of the input, where there is nothing to be matched by the `[^A-za-z]` expressions before the part that matches `The` or `the`. Word boundary anchors, on the other hand, are "zero-width" (i.e. they do not capture anything), which allows your expression to be matched at the beginning or at the end of your input.